# Change CSS applied to ::before using Polymer

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

Is it possible to change the CSS applied to an element specified with `::before`?

For example:
I am wanting to change this piece of CSS

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #e5e5e5;
}

.wrapper::before {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 15px); 
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 10px 10px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    pointer-events: none;
    content: "";
}
```

such that the `box-shadow` is applied at a specific time via javascript in something resembling this process...

```
addShadow : function() {
      var scroll = this.$.container.scrollTop;

      if(scroll >= 2) {
          this.$.wrapper.classList.add('shadow');
      } else {
          this.$.wrapper.classList.remove('shadow');
      }
  },
```

**Feel free to edit my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7yg8seta/) and give me some feedback**

Answer (score 4):

As you are already toggling the `.shadow` class, all you need to do is alter the css selector:

```
.wrapper.shadow::before {
```

Comment: Hey Richard, I can't get this to work. Is there any way you could edit my Fiddle that I have added to my question to show me what I am doing wrong?